# I want to delete last integers value swift

Tags: swift, string, int

I want to delete only integer value from any string. Is it possible or not?

```
let string = "kjgd5676idbh123456"
```

i want to result this  string = kjgd5676idbh

I want to delete only the last integer value. How to remove the last integer value?

Comment: Last integer value meaning only '6' or the trailing integer values '123456' ?

Comment: Please clarify your requirements. What result do you want from your `"kjgd5676idbh123456"` string? What about a string like `"dfgdg143j34fgg"`? Please [edit] your question (don't post comments) with all relevant details about your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search backwards for the first non-digit character and drop the trailing digits

```
let string = "kjgd5676idbh123456"
let result : String
if let range = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted, options: .backwards) {
    result = String(string[..<range.upperBound])
} else {
    result = Int(string) == nil ? string : ""
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to delete the whole value 123456 you can use regex `\\d+` to match any number with 1 digit or more and anchor it to the end of the string using the dolar sign `$`

```
let str = "kjgd5676idbh123456"
if let index = str.range(of: "\\d+$", options: .regularExpression)?.lowerBound {
    print("Last Number:", str[index...])  // 123456
    print("Prefix:", str[..<index])       // kjgd5676idbh
}
```

If you need to remove a single digit suffix you just need to remove the plus sign of your regex. `"\\d$"`

Comment: This regex is not going to work if there's letters at the end of the string though

Comment: Well that’s intentional

Comment: Same regular expression, used slightly differently: `let newstr = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\d+$", with: "", options: .regularExpression)`